# How do I display my result from a function on the web page. I want to display the average score and the letter grade. I have enclosed my code.

Tags: javascript, html

This may be a simple question, but I am in a class and just learning. I know the code works because the alert boxes work but I don't know how to display the result on the webpage.  Please help.  If you have a suggestion, let me know.

```
<html>

    <head>
    </head>

    <body>
    A: <input type = "text" id = "v" maxlength="3" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57'>
    <br>
    B: <input type = "text" id = "w" maxlength="3" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57'>
    <br>
    C: <input type = "text" id = "x" maxlength="3" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57'>
    <br>
    D: <input type = "text" id = "y" maxlength="3" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57'>
    <br>
    E: <input type = "text" id = "z" maxlength="3" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57'>
    <br>

    <button type = "button" id = "Average"> 
    Average </button>
    <div id = "Average">
    </div>
    <div id = "Letter">
    </div>
    </body>

    <script src = "LetterGrade.js"></script>
    <script src = "calcAvg.js"> 
    </script>
    <p>"Your average grade is: " </p>
    <p>"Your letter grade is: " + document.getElementById("Letter").value </p>

</html>
function Average(a,b,c,d,e)
{
    var v = parseInt(a);
    var w = parseInt(b);
    var x = parseInt(c);
    var y = parseInt(d);
    var z = parseInt(e)
    return (v + w + x + y + z) / 5;
}

function Display()
{
    var v = document.getElementById("v").value;
    var w = document.getElementById("w").value;
    var x = document.getElementById("x").value;
    var y = document.getElementById("y").value;
    var z = document.getElementById("z").value;
    var message = Average(v,w,x,y,z);

    document.getElementById("Average").value = message;

    window.alert(message);

    document.getElementById("Letter").value = LetterGrade(message);

    window.alert(LetterGrade(message));
}

document.getElementById("Average").addEventListener("click", Display);

function LetterGrade (grade)
{
    var Letter;
    if(grade >= 90)
    {
        Letter = "A";
    }
    else if ((grade >= 80) && (grade < 90))
    {
        Letter = "B";
    }
        else if ((grade >= 70) && (grade < 80))
    {
        Letter = "C";
    }
    else if ((grade >= 60) && (grade < 70))
    {
        Letter = "D";
    }   
    else
    {
        Letter = "F";
    }

    return Letter;

    console.log("Your letter grade is: " + Object.Letter);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
document.getElementById("Average").value = message;
document.getElementById("Letter").value = LetterGrade(message);
```

The `value` is property is more for `input` tags than anything. What you're looking for is `innerHTML`:

```
document.getElementById("Average").innerHTML = message;
document.getElementById("Letter").innerHTML = LetterGrade(message);
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("Average").textContent = message;` also works. One advantage to `textContent` over `innerHTML` is that any HTML characters like `<` will be rendered as text instead of having the browser attempt to interpret it as HTML

Comment: Thank you that code statement worked to display the average and letter grade on my webpage.  How would I add this text "Your average grade is: " to the code document.getElementById("Average").innerHTML = message; Same for "Your letter grade is: ".

Comment: Concatenate it. `document.getElementById("Average").innerHTML = 'Your average grade is: ' + message;` If that's the case, though, I'd suggest putting the text outside of the element you want to change: `<div>Your average grade is: <div id="Average"></div></div>`

Comment: Thanks again, the concatenation worked.  I tried the other, <div>Your average grade is: <div id="Average"></div></div> but did not get it to work.